# PowerShell: How to clear cache of included files?

Tags: powershell, caching

I include an external .ps1 into antother .ps1:

**foo.ps1:**

```
.("C:\test\bar.ps1");
$obj = [bar]::new();
$obj.out();
```

**bar.ps1**:

```
class bar{    
    $output;

    bar(){
        $this.output = 1;
    }

    [void] out(){
        write-host $this.output;
    }
}
```

The first time I execute `foo.ps1` in the *Windows PowerShell ISE* the output is "1", as expected.
Then I go to `bar.ps1` and change `$this.output = 1;` to `$this.output = 2;`. After executing `foo.ps1` again the output is still "1". When I change something in `foo.ps1`, like simply appending a new line, and execute it once again, the output becomes "2". Changing back, like removing the new line, will make an output of "1" again.

For me it looks like an caching issue. Is it possible to clear or disable the caching?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe.  Is there more to the scenario?

Comment: No, this is exactly the code I use. My PowerShell Version is 5.1.18362.145.